# Why Does the DSP Subtract 1 From my Equation?

Tags: vhdl, signal-processing, fpga, xilinx

I tried implementing in a DSP48E1:

`(A * B) - C`

From reading the manual:

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug479_7Series_DSP48E1.pdf

I figured I must have:

`OPMODE => "0110101"`

So that the outputs of the X, Y,  and Z multiplexers are:

- X and Y are the partial products of `M = A * B`, so that, `X + Y = M = A * B`
- `Z = C`

Then I set:

`ALUMODE => "0001"`

So that it should produce:

`-Z + (X + Y + CIN) - 1 = not(Z) + X + Y + CIN`

There is a note on page 35 which says "In 2s complement `-Z = not(Z) + 1`"

Therefore the result I consistently get is:

`-C + A * B -1`

Is there an easy way to correct this result? Or should I just register an addition of + 1 before the input?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `X*Y` in the above equations? Setting `CIN` may solve your problem, but I'm not familiar with direct instantiation of this DSP primitive.

Comment: No, from what I understand X and Y are the two partial products as seen on page 34.

I thought this too, but you look on page 37 then you have the options for the `CARRYINSEL` mux which I have left at 0. I've tried setting `CARRYIN` to 1 but it doesn't seem to make a difference. There must be something I'm missing as page 55 tells you this is exactly what it's for.

Comment: I edited your question again to clarify the value of X, Y and Z. Hope it is ok.

Comment: I have this opmode working in a design, with `CARRYIN` set to `'1'`, and I can't see anything wrong in what you have described. Are you definitely connecting to `CARRYIN`, and not `CARRYCASCIN`? If you are simulating, are you doing this using Vivado simulation libraries, or ISE? Although ISE has some 7-series device support, it is no longer maintained, so there could be errors in its simulation models. I'm also assuming that your opmode is not dynamically changing, and so this cannot be a pipelining problem.